# How to make a batch script to move files to a networked drive

Tags: batch-file

I have made a script to move files from a folder on my local machine to a networked drive, but I can't seem to get it to work.

```
move c:\Sourcefoldernam\*.* \\homeserver\e
```

Am I missing something for the files to move to the networked drive?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing a backslash

try

> move  c:\Sourcefoldername\*.* \\homeserver\e

Comment: you mean move c:\Sourcefoldername*.* \\homeserver\e

Comment: yes, I thought I did type "\\", strange.. I wonder if backslash is an escape character here.

Comment: also missing a slash after Sourcefoldername, try this move c:\Sourcefoldername\* \\homeserver\e

Answer (score 0):

Here is how we do it for our network locations at my work

```
REM Do a net use command just to see what's mapped
net use



REM Delete all network connections before we start
net use * /del /yes




REM Do another net use to make sure the connections are gone
net use

REM Map network connections to use in the script
net use S: \\folder\dir password /USER:user /persistent:no
net use T: \\folder\dir /persistent:no

REM Run the net use command to make sure everything is mapped correctly
net use

REM set the sourcedir variable to point to the directory you want to send it to
set sourcedir=S:

REM set the destdir variable to point to the mapped directory
set destdir=T:\folder\sub-folder\directory

move %sourcedir%\W* %destdir%\


REM Clean up by deleting all network connections before ending
net use * /del /yes

REM Run the net use command to make sure everything is disconnected
net use
```

Comment: The 
move C:\sourcefolder\* Y:\sourceDestination 
command did not work. 

Jakepens71 I tried your option but can't seem to get past the set sourcedir and destdir. I'm running this all in a CMD for now to make sure it works before I put it into a .bat file. I do

set sourcedir=C:\completed 
then 
set destdir=E:\ 
When I do this nothing shows that it set the directories...
I then do
move %sourcedir%\ %destdir%\

At this point it says the system cannot find the file specified.
@jakepens71

Comment: I do not believe you need the letters to the drive path in there. Just simply move %sourcedir%\W* %destdir%\

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the entire path, and with a * is enough

```
move [source folder] [destination folder]

move C:\sourcefolder\* Y:\sourceDestination
```